# Detect that a IIS Worker Process is deadlocked and recycle the Application Pool

Tags: asp.net, iis, powershell, deadlock, application-pool

Is it possible to use powershell to detect an IIS worker process thread deadlock and then trigger an Application Pool recycle?

The Reason: I have a website that calls an assembly in the GAC that sometimes just holds the thread in deadlock and the only fix is to recycle the Application Pool of the website in IIS, the annoying thing is that a user has to notice it before I am told, it would be good to automate this process.

Comment: It's almost impossible as IIS does not expose any API for that. If you do want to implement it, you need to utilize raw Win32 API, which is rather difficult for a PowerShell based solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. First we have to find a way to detect if the thread is deadlocked. I am guessing that you can probably do that with something as simple as a ping. Then we have to Recycle the App Pool.

```
# Load IIS module:
Import-Module WebAdministration

# Set a name of the site we want to recycle the pool for:
$site = "Default Web Site"

# Get pool name by the site name:
$pool = (Get-Item "IIS:\Sites\$site"| Select-Object applicationPool).applicationPool

#Check to see if the site is deadlocked.
if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName Server -Quiet))
{
    #Site is Deadlocked. Recycle the application pool:
    Restart-WebAppPool $pool
}
```

Comment: The weird thing is that the website works fine except for when a user goes to a specific page that calls the other assembly, so technically its not the worker process that has deadlocked, its just some of the threads in the pipeline. (discovered via Resource Monitor - Analyse Wait Chain)

Comment: It sounds like you need to find the issue with that other assembly, or have your code start a watchdog timer so that if no request is received after 10 seconds, throw an error or something that can be caught and handled or something like this (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163618.aspx). The issue is that it is very hard to detect deadlocked processes at the thread level without a lot of code. For ex. To use the Wait Chain Traversal API (i.e. how you detected it), See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681418(v=vs.85).aspx